# How to format this list in ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have the following list that shows: one icon, a user pic, name, and 2 icons on the left. 
I cannot align then properly in ionic, even when I add styling I cannot fix them.

Can you please give me a hint how to make this item be inline in the order I mentioned above?

```
<div class="list">
     <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#" style="margin-top:40px;">
                            <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                            <img class="circular-image" src="/Content/img/bill.jpg" />
                            <h2 style="display:inline; padding-left:10px;">F.joe</h2>
                            <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>

                        </a>

                        <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                            <img class="circular-image" src="/Content/img/bill.jpg" />
                            <h2 style="display:inline; padding-left:10px;">F.joe</h2>
                            <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
                        </a>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the flexbox to align the items inside the item, defining three sections .item-content-left, item-content-center (with flex-grow to expand) and .item-content-right

but for something simpler I would take Jake Stewart approach.

```
 <div class="list">
     <a class="item" href="#" >
         <div class='item-content'>
         <div class='item-content-left'>
              <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
         </div>
          <div class='item-content-center'>
               <img class="circular-image" src="/Content/img/bill.jpg" />
                <h2 >F.joe</h2>
          </div>                  
         <div class='item-content-right'>
             <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
              <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
         </div>
         </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item-content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items:  flex-start; 
}

.item-content-left{

}
.item-content-right{

}
.item-content-center{
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items:  flex-start; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lvu98pb/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Ionic's grid CSS component:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Try something like this:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img class="circular-image" src="/Content/img/bill.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>F.joe</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

You can mess with the row and col classes to give your list your desired look and feel. For example "col col-25" will make that column take up 25% of the screen.